# how to access clientside code object in handlebar in salesforce marketing cloud personalization web template

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, campaign, page-template, evergage

I am trying to develop a timer clock in marketing cloud personalization web template and i am kind of new to salesforce.
right now, i have a date set in `serverside` code as below:

```
export class timer_template implements CampaignTemplateComponent {
    
    dateProperty: DateTime;
    run(context: CampaignComponentContext) {
        return {dateProperty: this.dateProperty,
        };
    }

}
```

i want to access this dateproperty in clientside code and run a timer for 'days to go'

**my clientside code**：

```
(function() {
    const bannerTemplate = new timer_template();

    const contextFromServer = {
        campaign: {context.campaign},
        experience: {context.experience},
    };
    const returnedValue = bannerTemplate.run(contextFromServer);

    const dateProperty = returnedValue.dateProperty;

    function buildBindId(context) {
        return `${context.campaign}:${context.experience}`;
    }

    function getTimeRemaining(endtime){
        const total = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
        const days = Math.floor(total/(1000*60*60*24));

        return {
            days
        };
    }

    function apply(context, template) {
        const contentZoneSelector = SalesforceInteractions.mcis.getContentZoneSelector(context.contentZone);
        const remainingTime = getTimeRemaining(dateProperty);
        
        return SalesforceInteractions.DisplayUtils
            .bind(buildBindId(context))
            .pageElementLoaded(contentZoneSelector)
            .then((element) => {
                const html = template({
                    ...context,
                    remainingTime: remainingTime // Include remainingTime in the context
                });
                SalesforceInteractions.cashDom(element).html(html);
            });
    }
```

**handlebars**

```
{{#if remainingTime}}
<h2>
    {{remainingTime.days}} days
</h2>
```

i am unable to see the output on my content zone, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is possible. I believe you need to reference context.  {{context.remainingTime.days}}